# Sort ListView bound to ObservableCollection in XAML

Tags: sorting, xaml, listview, uwp, observablecollection

I have a `ListView` that is bound through XAML to an `ObservableCollection`. I used to do the sorting in code behind but there are many operations where I would have to keep in mind that the sorting needs to be refreshed.

So I wanted to make it more clean and make the sorting directly in XAML more dynamically.

Unfortunately I cannot find tags/attributes to do this. All examples I find are for WPF applications using `<CollectionViewSource.SortDescription>` which seems to be not supported in XAML, at least for now.

I found a `AdvancedCollectionView` control in the UWP Community Toolkit which I then used. This control uses the existing ObservableCollection and the ListView (source) is now bound to this AdvancedCollectionView.

It seems to work - so what's the problem.
1) I now have to use a huge Nu-Get package with many licenses (which I should have read :-) )
2) I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for the class that is bound to the ListView (the single item) so that the ListView gets refreshed when a property, e.g. the Title of an item changes. This used to work earlier, before I switched to AdvancedCollectionView but now the event raiser throws a `NullReferenceExcpetion`.

So I'm now asking myself if there isn't really a more Out-of-the-Box way to do the simple task of sorting a ListView by a bound property?

Comment: ". I used to do the sorting in code behind ",could I know how you do that? Did you mean you just want to do it in xaml without any code behind? Even the `AdvancedCollectionView`  is do the sorting code behind,beside it need a package referenced, can it meet  your demand?

Comment: Since the community toolkit is open source, you could just reference the section you need to try to build your own helper class.

Comment: I meant, that I sorted the ObservableCollection "manually" with a Sort() extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue with the AdvancedCollectionView occurs because there is currently a bug when no Filter property has been set.

I replaced the NuGet-Package with the complete source and debugged it to locate the error in the ItemOnPropertyChanged where it threw the NullReferenceException on line:

```
filterResult = _filter(item);
```

because "_filter" was null.

I reporeted the bug and it looks like a fix will be in version 2.2 of the Community Toolkit:
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1686